# Create false color images on Earth Engine

Tags: rgb, composite, band-ratio

I want to calculate some band ratio images on e.g. Aster imagary and display them as false color image.

For example I compute band ratio images on Aster as follow:

```
var BR1 = AsterImageMosaic.select('B01').divide(AsterImageMosaic.select('B3N'));
var BR2 = AsterImageMosaic.select('B01').divide(AsterImageMosaic.select('B09'));
var BR3 = AsterImageMosaic.select('B3N').divide(AsterImageMosaic.select('B09'));
```

Now I want to display these bands as FCC as R: BR1, G: BR2, B: BR3

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer for that. just create new image from defined images in previous section as follow
:

```
var FCC1=ee.Image.rgb(BR1, BR2, BR3)
```

Comment: Accept your own answer with the checkbox